# $ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \tfrac{n}{\log n} (\sqrt[n]{2n} -1) $?

Tags: analysis, limits

I've tried so hard to find this limit, could you help me?
$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \tfrac{n}{\log n} (\sqrt[n]{2n} -1) $ . Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: As per [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157147/elegant-solution-to-lim-limits-n-to-inftyn-sqrtna-1), we know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]x-1)=\ln(x)$, thus, what can you say about your limit?

Comment: I can't understand how to use your suggestion, could you show me that?

Comment: Your limit is of the following form: $$\frac c\infty$$Since we have a finite part divided by an unbounded part.

Comment: uuuuu ok, now i undestand! Thanks you :)

Comment: No problem! :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : the limit is not of the form $c/\infty$. The right answer is $1$ as given by zhw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The expression equals

$$\frac{n}{\ln n}(e^{(\ln 2n)/n}-1) = \frac{n}{\ln n}(\ln 2n)/n)\frac{e^{(\ln 2n)/n}-1}{(\ln 2n)/n}.$$

Recall $\lim_{u\to 0} (e^u-1)/u = 1.$