# Why is $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{x^{\frac{s+1}{n}}-1} = \dfrac{1}{s+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I believe the question tag is quite self-explanatory. Why is$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{x^{\frac{s+1}{n}}-1} = \frac{1}{s+1}$$

true? It looks like a case for l'hopitals rule, I'd say, but I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have by L'Hospital
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}x^{1/n-1}}{\frac{s+1}{n}x^{\frac{s+1}{n}-1}}$$
can you finish?

Comment: yes, I can, thanks, the rest is just elementary algebraic manipulations.

Answer (score 4):

We can use the standard limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n(x^{1/n} - 1)=\log x\tag{1}$$ in the following manner:
\begin{align}
L&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^{1/n} - 1}{x^{(s + 1)/n} - 1}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n(x^{1/n} - 1)}{n((x^{s + 1})^{1/n} - 1)}\notag\\
&= \frac{\log x}{\log x^{s + 1}}\notag\\
&= \frac{\log x}{(s + 1)\log x}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{s + 1}\notag
\end{align}

---

OP wants to know more about the standard limit $(1)$ above. There are two approaches possible. One approach is to start with equation $(1)$ as the definition of $\log x$ and then develop a full theory of exponential and logarithmic functions. This is available with all the details in [my blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html).

Another approach is to assume familiarity with exponential and logarithmic functions and in particular the relation $a^{b} = \exp(b\log a)$ and the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\exp(x) - 1}{x} = 1\tag{2}$$ Then we can see that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(x^{1/n} - 1) = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{x^{t} - 1}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\exp(t\log x) - 1}{t\log x}\cdot\log x = \log x$$ where $t = 1/n$.

There is also [another approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2157332/72031) which shows that limit $(1)$ is equal to $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}$ via limit of Riemann sum.

Comment: Can you explain the standard limit $ \lim_{n\to \infty} n \cdot x^{\frac{1}{n}} -n = log x $ ?

Comment: @ghthorpe: wait for few minutes for update in my answer.

Comment: @ghthorpe: See my updated answer.

Comment: Clearly the problem is much simpler as I now realized. Putting $u^n=x$ we can see that $u\to 1$ and the expression under limit is $(u-1)/(u^{s+1}-1)$ which tends to $1/(s+1)$ via the standard limit $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^n-a^n} {x-a} =na^{n-1}$.